# If statement - either one false

Tags: php, if-statement

Heres my code, i want to have it so if either the No Validation or Validation is not checked then the user has to "select a buy option"... my way below works but Is there a simpler way with just one if statement?

```
if ($buyoption == "With Validation") {
} else if ($buyoption == "No Validation") {
} else {
    $buyoptionError = "Please select a buy option";
    echo "$buyoptionError <br>";
    $YesorNo = 0;
}
```

Comment: you can just use `OR` operator if I am not wrong. `if (($buyoption == "With Validation") || ($buyoption == "No Validation")) { } else { $buyoptionError = "Please select a buy option"; ... }`

Comment: you may also use NOT and AND operator and rewrite your code

Comment: What should be the default value of `$YesorNo` ?

Comment: Default value is already preset to 1.. and if theres an error i set to 0

Comment: what about `if ($YesorNo === 0)` ?? since default value is 1

Comment: $YesorNo is only set to 0 if either No validation or With validation is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a switch:

```
switch($buyoption){

 case "With Validation":
  #code
  break;

 case "No Validation":
  #code
  break;

 default:
  $buyoptionError = "Please select a buy option";
  echo "$buyoptionError <br>";
  $YesorNo = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Optimized

```
if ($buyoption != 'With Validation' && $buyoption != "No Validation") {
     $buyoptionError = "Please select a buy option";
    echo "$buyoptionError <br>";
    $YesorNo = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use this

```
if (((trim($buyoption) === "With Validation") || (trim($buyoption) === "No Validation")))===false) {
$buyoptionError = "Please select a buy option";
echo "$buyoptionError <br>";
$YesorNo = 0;}else{
// your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ($YesorNo = ($buyoption == "With Validation" || $buyoption == "No Validation")) ? "": "Please select a buyoption";
```